# How to attach onClickListener to an invisible view

Tags: android, onclick, onclicklistener

I want to attach an onClickListener to an ImageView which is made `INVISIBLE`. I know I could set it to the `TRANSPARENT` color but due to certain reasons I don't want to do that and an `INVISIBLE` ImageView is not listening to clicks. Is there any way to achieve the required thing?

Comment: You want to be able to click on it? even when not visible?

Comment: yes, its for a game. there is an object, and if the object goes invisible and player still tries to tap that object (because of fast speed), player loses.

Comment: You should set its alpha to 0 then.

Comment: yeah, that's what I've to do now. Thanks though.

Answer (score 12):

No, INVISIBLE views don't receive touch events.  However there are a few alternatives you can use:

- Set the view's alpha to 0.  This would make it fully transparent.
- Create a 2nd view of the exact same size above the view and put the click handler on that.
- Put a touch handler on the parent and check if in the area of the invisible view when you detect a click.

Least work is probably top to bottom on that list.